# Disable smooth scrolling in Android Chrome 73

Tags: chrome-for-android

Is there a way to disable smooth scrolling in Android Chrome 73.X? It seems like it's now enabled for all sites by default, and setting it to “Disabled” in chrome://flags does nothing.

Motivation: The smooth scrolling behavior makes Ctrl+F-ing through long pages pretty painful (a couple seconds of pointless animation between each result).